# Problemas para mostrar contenido de una Api

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Estoy consumiendo cursos de dicha url el punto es que al dar tap en uno de los cursos listados que tengo por medio de un listview separated me debe llevar a una pantalla en donde me lista las lecciones de cada curso (otra url).

```
class CurseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CurseScreen> createState() => _CurseScreenState();
}

class _CurseScreenState extends State<CurseScreen> {
  List<ListCurseDetail> listCurse = [];
  ControllerListCurse _controllerHome = ControllerListCurse();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    isLoading = true;
    _cargarListCurse();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.038;
    final sm = 100.0, lg = 200.0;
    return Scaffold(
      /*appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          //padding:  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,),
          icon:  Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 35,
          ),
          tooltip: 'Back',
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 144, 12),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),*/

      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/Fondo GdR 2.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/botón descubre GdR.png',
                    width: 21,
                    height: 21,
                  ),
                ),
                //Container(width: 45,),
                Text(
                  //listCurse.length.toString(),
                  "Cursos",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontSize: fontsize,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    fontFamily: 'mifuente',
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  width: 45,
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            /* Text("prueba"),
            SingleChildScrollView(child: 
            SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height-110,
              child: 
            listviewBuilder())),*/
            Expanded(
              child: _listViewCategorias(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView _listViewCategorias() {
    return ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
        indent: 18,
        endIndent: 18,
        color: Color.fromARGB(143, 0, 0, 0),
      ),
      physics:
          const BouncingScrollPhysics(), //Esto agrega un efecto de rebote al hacer scroll

      itemBuilder: (_, i) => _categoriaListTile(
          i), //es una función que se llama para cada índice en la lista
      itemCount: (listCurse.length),
      //itemCount: (listCurse.length / 2).ceil(),
    );
  }

  _categoriaListTile(i) {
    return RowCurseScreen(
        titulo: listCurse[i].titulo,
        id: listCurse[i].id,
        descripcion: listCurse[i].descripcion);
  }

  _cargarListCurse() async {
    listCurse = await _controllerHome.getCursos();
    print(listCurse);
    /*print(listCurse[0]);
    print(listCurse[0].tematica);
    isLoading = false;*/

    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Aquí el widget RowCurseScreen

```
class RowCurseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int? id;
  String? tematica;
  String? titulo;
  String? descripcion;

  RowCurseScreen({
    Key? key,
    this.id,
    this.tematica,
    this.titulo,
    this.descripcion,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RowCurseScreen> createState() => _RowCurseScreenState();
}

class _RowCurseScreenState extends State<RowCurseScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final fontsizeT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05;
    //final fontsizeS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03;
    final fontsizeT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.052;
    final fontsizeS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.043;

//se muestra todo este widget en base a la longitud de la lista(listCurse)que recibe
//los datos provenientes de la api 
    final sm = 100.0, lg = 200.0;
    return widget.titulo == null
        ? const Text('No hay convenios para esta categoria')
        : GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => LessoCurseScreen(
                  id: widget.id,
                  titulo: widget.titulo,
                  descripcion: widget.descripcion,
                ),
              ));
            },
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,

                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  radius: 30,
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                        fit:BoxFit.cover,
                        'https://potapi.espaciocientifico.com/api/course/courseimage/${widget.id}'),
                         
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(widget.titulo.toString(),
              style:  TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontsizeT,
              ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(widget.descripcion.toString(),
              style:  TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontsizeS,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Entonces doy tap en el curso y me lleva a esta pantalla que es la encargada de mostrar las lecciones de cada curso.

```
class LessoCurseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final id;
  final titulo;
  final descripcion;
  LessoCurseScreen({
    Key? key,
    this.id,
    this.titulo,
    this.descripcion,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LessoCurseScreenState createState() => _LessoCurseScreenState();
}

class _LessoCurseScreenState extends State<LessoCurseScreen> {
  late List<ListDetailCurse> listLesson = [];
  ControllerLessonCurse _controllerLessonCurse = ControllerLessonCurse();

  bool isLoading = false;
  // String titulo = 'Categoria';

  @override
  void initState() {
    isLoading = true;
    _cargarlistLesson();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontsize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.075;
    //final sm = 100.0, lg = 200.0;
    return Scaffold(
      /*isLoading
        ? PageLoad()
        :*/
      /*appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          //padding:  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,),
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 35,
          ),
          tooltip: 'Back',
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 144, 12),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),*/
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/Fondo GdR 1.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.08,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                //const SizedBox(height: 50),
                IconButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/botón descubre GdR.png',
                    width: 21,
                    height: 21,
                  ),
                ),
                /*Container(
                  width: 75,
                ),*/
                Text(
                  'Lecciones Del Curso',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontSize: fontsize,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    fontFamily: 'Mont-Book',
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05,
            ),
              ],
            ),
            //const SizedBox(height: 20),
            
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
            ),
            Expanded(child: 
                _listViewCategorias(),
                )
                
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView _listViewCategorias() {
    return ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
              indent: 18,
              endIndent: 18,
              color: Color.fromARGB(143, 0, 0, 0),
            ),
        physics:  BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (_, i) => _categoriaListTile(i),
        itemCount: (listLesson.length));
  }

  _categoriaListTile(count) {
    print(listLesson[count].titulo);
    return ColumnLessonScreen(
        titulo: listLesson[count].titulo,
        id: listLesson[count].id, //para la imagen
        contenido: listLesson[count].contenido, //para la imagen
        descripcion: listLesson[count].descripcion,
        multimediaLeccion:listLesson[count].mutimediaLeccion,
        );
  }

/*  _categoriaListTile(count) {
    int countFinal = count * 2;
    if (countFinal + 1 >= listLesson.length) {
      return ColumnLessonScreen(
        // foto: categorias[countFinal].imagenConvenio,
        id: listLesson[countFinal].id,
        // tematica: listLesson[countFinal].tematica,
        descripcion: listLesson[countFinal].descripcion,
        titulo: listLesson[countFinal].titulo,
      );
    } else {
      return ColumnLessonScreen(
        // foto: categorias[countFinal].imagenConvenio,
        id: listLesson[countFinal].id,
        // tematica: listLesson[countFinal].tematica,
        descripcion: listLesson[countFinal].descripcion,
        titulo: listLesson[countFinal].titulo,
        id1: listLesson[countFinal + 1].id,
        // tematica1: listLesson[countFinal + 1].tematica,
        descripcion1: listLesson[countFinal + 1].descripcion,
        titulo1: listLesson[countFinal + 1].titulo,
      );
    }
  }*/

  _cargarlistLesson() async {
    listLesson = await _controllerLessonCurse.getLesson(widget.id);
    print(listLesson[0]);
    //print('listLesson[0]');

    isLoading = false;

    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

y el widget de las lecciones

```
class ColumnLessonScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int id;
  String titulo;
  String? contenido;
  String? descripcion;
  MutimediaLeccion? multimediaLeccion;

  ColumnLessonScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
    required this.titulo,
    this.contenido,
    this.descripcion,
    this.multimediaLeccion,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColumnLessonScreen> createState() => _ColumnLessonScreenState();
}

class _ColumnLessonScreenState extends State<ColumnLessonScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontsizeT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.052;
    final fontsizeS = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.043;

    final sm = 100.0, lg = 200.0;
    return widget.multimediaLeccion!.data.isEmpty
        ? Container()
        
        : GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              //verifica el tipoArchivo del primer objeto en la lista de multimedia dentro del objeto multimediaLeccion.
              if (widget.multimediaLeccion!.data[0].tipoArchivo == "pdf") {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PdfScreen(
                    id: widget.id,
                    titulo: widget.titulo,
                    multimediaLeccion: widget.multimediaLeccion,
                  ),
                ));
              }
              else if(widget.multimediaLeccion!.data[0].tipoArchivo == "html"){
                   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HtmlScreen(
                    //id: widget.id,
                    //titulo: widget.titulo,
                    multimediaLeccion: widget.multimediaLeccion,
                  ),
                ));
              }
            },
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  radius: 30,
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.network(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        'https://potapi.espaciocientifico.com/api/course/courseimage/${widget.id}'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //! indica al compilador que estás seguro de que una expresión no será nula en tiempo de ejecución, a pesar de que el sistema de tipos de Dart podría considerarla potencialmente nula.

              title: Text(
                widget.titulo!,
                //widget.multimediaLeccion?.data?.first?.titulo ?? 'Título no disponible',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: fontsizeT,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                widget.descripcion!,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: fontsizeS,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Dejaré las capturas para que ustedes entiendan mejor.

[image: pantalla de cursos]

Si doy en el primer id o elemento va bien me enseña las lecciones de esta forma

[image: pantalla de lecciones]

Pero en todos los demás simplemente no enseña nada quedando de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que al dar tap en los elementos que no muestran nada. Si se ven los datos en consola por lo tanto asumo que el error es de lógica de mostrar data y no de el consumo de la api.